# Show options on dropdown menu from a column - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, indexing

I have a following code:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
  include("control/connect.php");

  $query = NULL;
  $query= "select * from category";           
  $result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

.....

```
<select name="categoryname" id="">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['categoryid']; ?>">

<?php echo $row['categoryname']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

But then, here's the problem:

[image]

An the other 3 options (The data has 3 rows in the table):
[image]

What's wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Problem: the `categoryname` is undefined. have you this column in your  table ?

Comment: seems like categoryname is not a column of your table, maybe a typo?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M I have that column in my table. I have checked it from phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Fabio I have that column in my table. I have checked it from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @ngfajarchandra are you sure it about uppercase lowercase? it is really telling you that this column does not exist

Comment: @Fabio yes. I forgot that it's case sensitive. I have fixed it and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply ensure that you have typed `categoryname` correctly. It should be the same as you have column name in database. And it is case sensitive. So, if column is called categoryName, `$row['categoryname']` will throw a notice

Comment: well I forgot that it's case sensitive. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are trying to use the category name even before it is defined. Use this:

```
<?php if(isset($row['categoryname'])) {echo $row['categoryname'];} ?>
```

OR may be you don't have a `categoryname` column in your table